# Narrowing generic type which is keyof type without specifying generic argument

Tags: typescript

Apologies if this is duplicate somewhere, my google-fu was failing to find the correct words to narrow down the results.

I'm trying to create a helper function to re-use some functionality, and can't quite figure out if/how I can achieve it.

Given a function (or type) with generics, where one argument is a key of a specified generic type, having the function return type be determined as the return type of that specific property on the generic type, and not a union of every property type on the generic type.

```js
interface MyObject {
  readonly foo: Date;
  readonly bar: number;
  readonly wizz: string;
  readonly bang: boolean;
}

function getHelpers<ItemType>(key: keyof ItemType) {
  return (item: ItemType) => item[key];
}

const res = getHelpers<MyObject>('bang');
// Has type of `(item: MyObject) => string | number | boolean | Date`, when I need it to have `(item: MyObject) => boolean`
```

I know if I add a secondary generic argument, which narrows down the key type, then it works:

```
function getHelpers<ItemType, KeyType extends keyof ItemType>(key: KeyType) {
  return (item: ItemType) => item[key];
}

const res = getHelpers<MyObject, 'bang'>('bang'); // Has typed of `(item: MyObject) => boolean`
```

But I'd rather not have to duplicate the key by specifiying the generic argument every time I call the function, if at all possible.

Comment: `'bang'` (in `getHelpers<MyObject>('bang')`) will always be a **literal**, right? Never a runtime value?

Comment: This is a *really* interesting question.

Comment: Isn't this one of those UnionToIntersection kind of cases? Not that I have a specific solution... :) But it's basically about making sure the type argument is only one key and not a union of keys, right?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, always a literal, for at least on what I'm trying to do anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
interface MyObject {
    readonly foo: Date;
    readonly bar: number;
    readonly wizz: string;
    readonly bang: boolean;
}
```

Unfortunately this is not possible without function currrying. Your second option is the right approach. Ideally we would like to specify `ItemType` but infer `KeyType`. This is unfortunately not possible. We either infer all type parameters, or we have to specify them all. There is a feature proposal to support partial inference, but it has been postponed several times and is not currently on the road map.

The solution is to use two function calls, for the first one we specify `ItemType` and we let inference work for the second call.

```
function getHelpers<ItemType>() {
    return function <KeyType extends keyof ItemType>(key: KeyType) {
        return (item: ItemType) => item[key];
    }
}

const res = getHelpers<MyObject>()('bang'); // Has typed of `(item: MyObject) => boolean`
```

Comment: Is partial inference really the ideal solution? To me that would still not look clean. *Ideally* I'd be able to constrain the type to exactly what I want (which is exactly one of the keys as a literal type, not any subtype).

Comment: @IngoBürk The solution above does not constrain `K` not to be a union. What it does is infer `K` based on the argument type. There is no builtin `oneof` constrain, although that has been proposed. Not allowing a union is possible, but requires like you hint at `UnionToIntersection`. The reason OP has a union originally is that no inference occurs for the key. So we want the key inferred. But at the same time, since there is nowhere to infer the item type from we want to specify it manually. So yes I think, partial inference, would be required to type this in a single call.

Comment: @IngoBürk forgot to mention, we want the key inferred because we need to use it in typing the return of the innermost function as `ItemType[KeyType]` ( that is the inferred return type of the function) without inferring the key the return type is just `ItemType[keyof Item Type]`

Comment: Thanks! I've seen a couple of libraries have the same pattern, of having a generic'd function and return a function to further call, but didn't put it together that it was to solve the same issue as what I was having!